# Update SQL server local table column from linked server table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have  local and a linked server tables in SSMS

- local `[Arc].[dbo].[Record]`
- linked server `SQLSERVR.[ArcReport].[dbo].[RecordRemote]`

when I query

- `select * from [Arc].[dbo].[Record]`
- `select * from SQLSERVR.[ArcReport].[dbo].[RecordRemote]`
  It brings results.

But when I query

```
    UPDATE [Arc].[dbo].[Record]
    SET [Arc].[dbo].[Record].Column1= SQLSERVER.[ArcReport].[dbo].[RecordRemote].Column2 
    WHERE [Arc].[dbo].[Record].id = 16
```

or

```
UPDATE localR
  SET localR.Column1= remoteR.Column2 
  FROM [Arc].[dbo].[Record] AS localR
  INNER JOIN SQLSERVER.[ArcReport].[dbo].[RecordRemote].Column2 AS remoteR
  ON localR.id= [SQLSERVER].[ArcReport].[dbo].[RecordRemote].id
```

it says 
The multi-part identifier "SQLSERVER.ArcReport.dbo.RecordRemote.Column2" could not be bound.

Comment: Because `SQLSERVER.[ArcReport].[dbo].[RecordRemote].Column2` has no context. What row from `SQLSERVER.[ArcReport].[dbo].[RecordRemote].Column2` are you after? You, likely, should be using a `FROM` and a `JOIN`.

Comment: Two things wrong here: `SET` does not permit any aliases or names other than the column name (so use `SET Column1`) and to update from another table as a source, you'll have to use a `FROM` clause.

Comment: Also [3+ part naming on Columns will be Deprecated](https://wp.larnu.uk/3-part-naming-on-columns-will-be-deprecated/) and should be avoided. You are far better off aliasing your objects in the `FROM` and using those to qualify your columns. This avoids the use of a feature that will be deprecated and possibly removed in a future version, and makes your code much more succinct and readable.

Comment: @JeroenMostert `SET` does allow 2+ naming in an `UPDATE` statement (this doesn't mean you should). [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=4ab1f6eaa35f9ed8b464e960e1bad4c7)

Comment: @Larnu: Hmm, so it does. There's *some* context where aliases fail in an `UPDATE`, though. But now I can't remember exactly what that is. :P

Comment: Perhaps you're thinking of something like `UPDATE ST SET SomeTable.ID = 1 FROM dbo.SomeTable ST;` @JeroenMostert ?

Comment: @Larnu what exactly is the = 1 you mention? i need the to update a column with the value of another

Comment: @Larnu also in your first question, there is only one raw to both tables

Comment: It is in response to [Jeroen Mostert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4137916/jeroen-mostert) [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71940845/update-sql-server-local-table-column-from-linked-server-table?noredirect=1#comment127122240_71940845), @PanMarkosian .

Comment: I assume by "raw" you mean row, @PanMarkosian ; though it doesn't matter, 1 row or 1 billion, you can't reference a column (using deprecated 2+ naming or not) without the context in the `FROM`.

Comment: You meant "raw"? So what is a raw?

Comment: @Larnu sorry for the autocorrect.  i meant row, as you correctly assumed

Comment: Maybe that's just me, but combination of bounty offered, `ssms` tag and lack of elementary knowledge about SQL syntax smells fishy. Is this work interview task or what?

Comment: No, i am just in rush, and cant find the answer quickly cause i am Jr dev

Comment: So what's wrong with Aaron's answer..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have made a mistake in your SQL query (see 3rd image).

1. You can not use a column in the JOIN only tables go there (see 1st image)
2. Since you defined and alias for SQLSERVER.[ArcReport].[dbo].[RecordRemote] as remoteR you must use it to access its fields ([see SQL Aliases for more info](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp) and 2nd image)
   [image]
   [image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to perform a *join* so that SQL Server knows what row to update from.

```
UPDATE localR
  SET localR.Column1 = remoteR.Column2
  FROM Arc.dbo.[Record] AS localR
  INNER JOIN LinkedServerName.ArcReport.dbo.RecordRemote AS remoteR
  ON <some join condition between localR and remoteR>;
```

BTW your syntax wouldn't work locally, either. It essentially boils down to:

```
UPDATE dbo.T1
  SET C1 = dbo.T2.C2;
```

This is simply invalid syntax. You can't surprise add a table reference like that.

Answer (score 1):

Your join syntax is wrong :

```
INNER JOIN SQLSERVER.[ArcReport].[dbo].[RecordRemote].Column2 AS remoteR <= column2 is not a table
```

When doing a join, you join 2 tables (not columns), with a join condition on these 2 tables :

That makes :

```
UPDATE localR
SET localR.Column1= remoteR.Column2 
FROM [Arc].[dbo].[Record] AS localR
INNER JOIN SQLSERVER.[ArcReport].[dbo].[RecordRemote] AS remoteR
ON localR.id= remoteR.id
```

Answer (score 0):

In SQL server inner join is not necessary while updating a table from another table, where clause will do the trick. The simplify solution for your problem would be:

```
  UPDATE Record 
  SET Record.Column1= remoteR.Column2 
  FROM SQLSERVER.[ArcReport].[dbo].[RecordRemote] AS remoteR
  where Record.id= [SQLSERVER].[ArcReport].[dbo].[RecordRemote].id and Record.id = 16
```